# Get IP Address in Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

When associating a cloud service with a specific virtual network, the instance automatically gets an IP from the selected subnet range.

Is there a way to know this IP dynamically from within the instance itself? If so, is this information available as soon as the instance is created, for instance at the time when startup tasks are executed?

If not, is there a way to get this IP at any time after the instance is created, from outside the instance, programmatically?

I prefer a PowerShell solution, but anything would do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are from the instance, the IP Address is assigned at boot time. So by the time a start-up task is executed (PaaS / Cloud Service) you can determine the IP Address by just enumerating the network cards. Or getting en IP Endpoint.

A sample powershell (which has never been tested) would look something like this:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime")
$ipEndpoint = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment]::CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Endpoint1"].IPEndpoint
```

Now you have the `$ipEndpoint` variable which is of .NET type `IPEndpoint` and holds the local IP Address of the VM.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the internal LAN IP (same I get when doing an ipconfig), not the virtual network IP.

Comment: what do you mean by "The Virtual Network IP"?! It gives you the Direct IP Address (or DIP), not the Virtual IP Address (VIP, the public one) of the deployment. There is also a public IP Address of the VNet Gateway if you set-up cross-premises connectivity. So please explain better which exact IP Address you need.

Comment: If you have added the Cloud Service in the Virtual Network, the IP Address which you get via `ipconfig` and via the `InstanceEndpoints` **is** the IP Address from the Sub-net assigned, which **is within the Virtual Network**.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right. I'm pretty sure it showed something else first time I tested... Maybe some weird configuration.